# Unable to run application on IE while testing with Katalon

Tags: automated-testing, ie, katalon

Tried all the solutions available on the web, tried configuring to the latest version but still the test cases fail in Katalon Studio while it is tested on Internet Explorer. The same script works perfectly fine in Chrome and Firefox. If someone else faced the same problem and solved it, please let me know how!

Comment: post your error message

Answer (score 1):

Configure the IE browser like given in the [link](https://forum.katalon.com/t/unable-to-execute-tests-on-ie-11/6065/7) and try. Make sure your IE version is more than 7.

> 1. In Katalon - go to Project -> Settings -> Execution -> Default -> IE – click on Add and add these values {name =
>      ignoreProtectedModeSettings, type = Boolean, value = true}
> 2. Followed steps here - https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD/Internet+Explorer+Configurations 6
> 3. Instead of checking the Protected Mode – just unchecked the protected modes for all zones including in advanced.

Try this....

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I have already tried all these methods but it didnt work. Though I found a solution by replacing click with Send Keys and placing delay after every small operation and now it works perfectly fine.